# Add comment to a Question

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, reputation, comments

How much reputation/points does one need to have in order to add a comment to a question? 
Suppose, I see a question, but i do not want to answer it..all i want to do is add a comment on that question to ask for some details like asking the user to share some more code/inputs or stuff like that! So how much point/reputation do i need so that I get to see a

> "add comment"

link below each each and every question i come across?

I would be glad if someone can share any inputs on this. 
Thank you.

Comment: You want to add the reputation tag, I think. Also, it should be easy to search for the answer to this.

Comment: You need 50 reputation points on ordinary sites, 1 point here on Meta.

Comment: @Bart Thank you for your reply. I do no think that this is a possible duplicate of the link that you have shared. Your link discusses Comments in general while I have put up a specific question regarding comments on questions.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, the link states: "Users with **at least 50 reputation** may comment on any post." That makes it a duplicate

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for the suggestion! should have given you +1 for that but cant due to low reputation. :P Added "reputation" tag as well. Thanx! :)

Comment: @probablyPekka So 50 repuations? I believe that is the answer. Thanks mate! :)

Comment: Yep, what @probablyPekka says. It's a dupe because that exact requirement is outlined in that post. I should have been a bit more clear on the exact relevant statement perhaps. P.s. you can find all relevant privilege levels at http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges or the equivalent page for any site within the network.

Comment: @Bart Need not worry. got the answer that I was searching for. Purpose solved. thanx guys! :)